# Payment Gateway for Pakistan

Tags: payment-gateway

I am from Pakistan, I developed an *ecommerce website*, now I want to integrate some payment gateway like  *Authorize/paypal/stripe* etc, 
I don't know which payment gateway is available in Pakistan, and which one is the best to be used in Pakistan. 
If someone already have an experience of using some payment gateway in Pakistan, please let me know.

Comment: I am developing an ios app and a website. Facing same issue. Anybody know which payment gateway available in Pakistan have iOS api?

Comment: @NaXir I think Skrill is the best option for you. (Sorry for late reply :) )

Comment: There's nayapay arc available as well now. It provides a payment gateway.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A.o.A Afrif,

For Pakistanis, its very difficult to have ecommerce payment gateway as the biggest and easiest payment processor Paypal isn't supported here. So you can have following options:

1. 2Checkout (supports both cards and Paypal)
2. Skrill
3. UBL Go Green
4. HBL (Setup Fee Rs. 40,000/-)
5. MCB (Setup Fee Rs. 50,000/-)
6. UBL (Setup Fee Rs. 50,000/-)
7. [Easy Paisa](https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay-merchant/faces/pg/site/Login.jsf) (Download Registration Guide)
8. JazzCash
9. FonePay
10. UPaisa
11. Finja

    UBL Go Green is just launched and they provide payment gateway on request. Check the details here. https://www.ubldirect.com/corporate/ublgogreen.aspx either email them or contact a branch manager. If it is tough for you then probably 2checkout will be good incase you suspect that a lot of your customers will have paypal, else, go for Skrill.

Comment: I want to make an iOS app aswel as Website. As per my research 2Checkout doesnot have iOS api. Stripe is not available in Pakistan. Skrill also don't have any iOS api. Any help?

Comment: Well You can either use the payment gateway supplied by IOS, or you can implement a coupon based system, redirecting the users to your website to pay even for subscription, then give them a unique coupon and make the app check the coupon each time they access the premium feature, in that way you can use any payment gateway

Comment: Easy Paisa's link is not available at the moment

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada Thanks. Updated the link however they aren't actively accepting new signups right now

Comment: @MetaPakistani I guess https://foree.co/about also comes up under the same category.

Comment: which one is best if our customer base is from middle east in terms of taxes and dollar conversion. secondly if we have 2checkOut implemented, can we take payPal payments although we dont have PayPal in Pakistan.  Or any suggestions how we can get payments from clients who pay through PayPal.  Thanks

Comment: I reckon the following options can be used in projects if you are operating in Pakistan:

1. SimPaisa
2. Foree: https://foree.co/business/onyourwebsite
3. PayPro

Answer (score 9):

[Telenor Easy Pay](http://www.easypaisa.com.pk/en/services/easypay-customer)

You can use the EasyPay payment gateway introduced by telenor in Pakistan. It covers the features that you need (ecommerce website integration). Plus it has the value added features of easyPaisa too i.e. someone who cannot pay online using credit/debit card, can pay physically in the form of cash to an easy paisa shop. You will need to look into the site for more information.

Comment: Thank You Mohsin Ali !
Does Easy Pay provide payment gateway, so that I can integrate it in my website?

Comment: @Bangash Yes they do provide the gateway.

Comment: @sp3tsnaz sir can you please help me guiding how to integrate php and easy paisa

Comment: @root Please see this link https://www.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/onlinepaymentsdeveloper

Comment: which one is best if our customer base is from middle east in terms of taxes and dollar conversion. secondly if we have 2checkOut implemented, can we take payPal payments although we dont have PayPal in Pakistan.  Or any suggestions how we can get payments from clients who pay through PayPal.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Stripe is not available in Pakistan, as of yet!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, many payment gateway that take payments by credit cards impose restrictions on many countries such as Pakistan.

As far as I know, many people living in these countries use cryptocurrencies to get paid. Getting paid with cryptocurrencies is now very common, and when fixed-priced cryptocurrencies such as USDT are preferred, you will not be affected by volatility.

There are many payment gateway that make it easy to get paid with crypto money. https://payid19.com is one of them. You can withdraw the payment you receive by converting it to cash from the local exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Some new services are also added to the list (in recent times), choose what suits for your bussiness needs.

> 1- GoLootLO [by statebank of pakistan]

> 2- Paypak

> 3- Fonepay

hope it works for you.